# Joomla - 500 View not found [name, type, prefix]

Tags: php, joomla, components, joomla3.0

I am developing a **joomla component** in my **localhost**, every thing is ok on the **localhost** but when i create installation package and install the component on the **online** host i get **500 view not found** error

PS. I added all view files in the **package** also added views folder to installation **xml** file
also i checked files in the host , every needed file exists and there is no missing file.

another thing that i should say is that im running joomla **3.3.0** in localhost but **3.3.3** in online host.

I read all "view not found" articles in the internet :D but i couldn't find a solution :(

Regards

### Edit :

i uninstalled the component from localhost and installed component package on it again , every thing works fine , so the error is on the host. i changed files permission but still have same error.

Comment: 500 error is usually permissions issue. check that your files have appropriate permissions

Comment: I changed permission for **view.html.php** and **tmpl/default.php** from 640 to 750 but nothing changed

Comment: Only in the online host this error exists , I uninstalled component from localhost and installed package on it , every thing is ok . but on online host i see error :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joomla can't find the view with the given name. Besides @TheKrotek considerations, you should check the filename capitalization.  Windows, for some wild reason, cannot tell "a" from "A" in a filename.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a permissions issue at all. Joomla simply can't find the view with given name. Check your view name VERY carefully. It should be MyComponentViewMyPage, not myComponentViewmyPage or MycomponentViewMypage. Joomla is damn sensitive to this stuff.

Here's an example:

```
class SmartShoutboxViewShout extends JViewLegacy
```

Smart Shoutbox is the name of the component and Shout is a page it belongs.

Comment: also check the filename capitalization, Windows, for some wild reason, cannot tell "a" from "A" in a filename.

Comment: I changed the folder name of view from _reportedErrors_ to _reportederrors_ and problem solved :)
Thank you very much

Comment: @RiccardoZorn make your comment an answer to vote it.